# clang-format Pointer Alignment

Tags: c, clang-format

I need use clang-format to take my source code in a style. I try used the Linux kernel .clang-format, and take some modification in it.
But now one thing didn't come true:

```
/* This is clang-format result: */
struct one_name {
    int *   n1; /* Ummmm... */
    int     n2;
    double *p;
};

/* But I wanna this: */
struct one_name {
    int    *n1; /* The pointer is close to var name. */
    int     n2;
    double *p;
};
```

How to modify the .clang-format for the "int   *n1"?

Answer (score 1):

I had found out the reason: The version of clang-format and LLVM is too low (6.0.0)!
If use 13.0.0 with the same .clang-format file, "PointerAlignment: Right" can give the good format!

With this command to check version, such as:

```
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 13.0.0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `.clang-format` is in your project directory, and make sure use

```sh
clang-format -style=file yourCode.c
```

And your `.clang-format` should have a line like

```yaml
---
PointerAlignment: Right
```

For more options, visit https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modify my C code into the style which I hope, then try use the command "clang-format -style=file yourCode.c". I find out the .clang-format can be updated. But the pointer place is still not close with var name. I will try to study the web (ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: I would recommend you to do some control-of-variable tests to make sure your clang-format and `.clang-format` file really do an effect on the format as you expected. For example, change some other options and see if they will take effect. There could be something that is missing. For example, clang-format does not modify files in place, unless you explicitly pass an `-i` flag. Not sure if you have checked that. Also check that there is no grammar error in your C file. For a broken file, clang-format might not understand it.

Comment: For the specific option that controls the pointer alignment (left / middle / right), I am pretty sure that is *the* option.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now I had found out the reason: The version of LLVM and clang-format is too low (6.0.0) in my service PC. I use the version 13.0.0 with the same ".clang-format" in my local PC, "PointerAlignment: Right" can give the good format which I want as you said.  I will check with my colleague who is the server PC manager, to update the clang-format and LLVM version. Thanks again : )

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you feel my answer helps, you might consider giving it an upvote (upward triangle) and/or accepting it (tick).

Comment: I'm a new user in stackoverflow, sorry for don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote...

Comment: Ah ... I see. Thank you for the clarification. I am happy as always that I can offer some help.